# how to organize graph nodes to draw using java 2d

Tags: java, graph, java-2d, graph-algorithm

I created a program that builds and draw nested cyclic graphs (with undirected edges) in a JFrame using java awt.

The problem is that if the position of the nodes is not explicitly specified, or created at random, the graph becomes very messy, with edges crossing and vertex colliding.

I would like to implement an algorithm for repositioning to better distribute the nodes, in a more homogeneous and clean way.

Can someone help me?

Comment: You mention awt and JFrame?   Did you use AWT or Swing? or Both?

Comment: Both. The GUI JFrame and draw methods AWT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to look at [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/), which is a program to do exactly this (render graphs). It has a Java API, so you could integrate it into your program, and it's open-source, so if you'd rather implement a solution yourself, perhaps their code could provide some inspiration (just remember to check the license!)

In addition, their website has [a list of resources pertaining to graph drawing theory](http://www.graphviz.org/Theory.php), which sounds exactly like what you need.

Comment: I really need to implement, without using any library. this is for college. I looked at the code for the graphviz and found nothing useful or easy to understand =/

Comment: I found some more helpful stuff on their site - http://www.graphviz.org/Theory.php is a list of articles, books etc on the topic of drawing graphs. I suspect this problem will be non-trivial, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

[JGraphX](http://www.jgraph.com/jgraph.html) is native Java and includes automatic layouting options. Disclaimer - I do contribute to the project.